# Display text over the icon in JXLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, swingx

I'm using SwingX label for a image select/preview.
I need to show both text and icon together but when I set icon the text disappear!
How can I show text over the icon on a JXLabel?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there no issue with that, there are two ways

1.correct way (implemented in the API, good habits, blablabla)

```
JLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER); 
// search for equivalent in SwingX
```

2.crazy way to set proper `LayoutManager` for `JXLabel` and put there another `JXLabel` to the desired coordinates `Location`